# Split a c function into threads

Tags: c, multithreading

I have a c application handling float tables purposed for Radix4 calculation. Now I want it to be split into two threads in order to run it on a multicore system, First, this is the function structure:

```
void radix4(float* x, float* y, N)
{
   for (l = 1; l <= PMAX; l++)
   {
      n = pow_4[l];//LUT for power of 4
      for (c =0; c < n; c=c+4)
      {
         //Loading some parameters from a look-up table
        n2  =LUT_n2[l][c];
        N2  =LUT_n2[l][c+1];
        N2_2=LUT_n2[l][c+2];
        N2_3=LUT_n2[l][c+3];
        factor = TWIDDLE_LIMIT/(range*4);

          while ((k < range) && ( range > 7))
          {//loading data from input tables
           //Computing butterflies
           //Loading twiddles
           //Computing final values
           //Store result in the same table
          }
          while ((k<range) && (range<=7))
          {
           //loading data from input tables
           //Computing butterflies
           //Loading twiddles
           //Computing final values
           //Store result in the same table
          }
      }
   }
}
```

the while loops are unrolled.
Now what I want to understand is how can i know which parts can be split into threads and could give some hints on how to do it because I'm reading a lot of stuffs that made me a little bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create two functions which does the jobs. I presume the values for k and range are already defined in the program.
Using boost/threads.

Johan

```
    #include <boost/thread.hpp>

    void task1() 
    { 
        while ((k < range) && ( range > 7))
        {
           //loading data from input tables
           //Computing butterflies
           //Loading twiddles
           //Computing final values
           //Store result in the same table
        }
    }

    void task2() 
    { 
        while ((k<range) && (range<=7))
        {
           //loading data from input tables
           //Computing butterflies
           //Loading twiddles
           //Computing final values
           //Store result in the same table
        }
    }

void radix4(float* x, float* y, N)
{
   for (l = 1; l <= PMAX; l++)
   {
      n = pow_4[l];//LUT for power of 4
      for (c =0; c < n; c=c+4)
      {
         //Loading some parameters from a look-up table
        n2  =LUT_n2[l][c];
        N2  =LUT_n2[l][c+1];
        N2_2=LUT_n2[l][c+2];
        N2_3=LUT_n2[l][c+3];
        factor = TWIDDLE_LIMIT/(range*4);

        thread thread_1 = thread(task1);
        thread thread_2 = thread(task2);

        // join
        thread_2.join();
        thread_1.join();

   }
}
```

Comment: The question is for C, not C++.

Comment: 1) This is not C! 2) Code-only answer 3) Why two function? 4) No, it does not "work the same"! Different languages!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to optimize an FFT routine. You may want to look into thread pools, since you're going to compute multiple FFTs over the lifetime of the application. Take a look at [FFTW](http://fftw.org/)'s website and see how their API is structured.

And for the answer to your question, you can "split" your problem into `N` threads (Let's pick `N = 2`). Then what you need to do is basically de-interleave (even in top half of array, and odd in bottom for `N = 2`). And run another routine to compute FFT for the subset of those arrays (`N` of them). Then you can put the arrays back using the identity/symmetry properties and interleave the array again.

Hope this helps.